# Center align captions for subfigures

Tags: subcaption

I would like to **center align** the subcaptions w.r.t. to their corresponding subfigures, like this:

[image]

My current attempt make them **left-aligned** even though I have specified `\centering` in the corresponding `\begin{subfigure} ... \end{subfigure}` block.

All I want is to move the entire subcaption to the position of the *red* box. The other formats should remain unchanged.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,font=small,labelfont={sc,bf},labelsep=period}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang,font=footnotesize,labelfont=up,singlelinecheck=false}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{
            Caption of subfigure1 \\ (e.g., load case 1 and 2).
        }
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{
            Caption of subfigure2 \\ (e.g., load case 3 and 4).
        }
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{
        Comparison of two subfigures.
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the options `format=hang` and `singlelinecheck=false`?

Comment: @Mico Yes, but it doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the argument `justification=centering` to `\captionsetup[subfigure]{...}`. While you're at it, you might as well delete the arguments `format=hang`  and `singlelinecheck=false` since they don't appear to do anything useful.

I'd also get rid of (or, at least, comment out) all three `\centering` directives as they don't do anything except create needless code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,font=small,
              labelfont={sc,bf},labelsep=period}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize,
              labelfont=up,
              %%singlelinecheck=false,
              %%format=hang,
              justification=centering % <-- new
             }
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}} % that's the default


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    %%\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        %%\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption of subfigure 1\\(e.g., load cases 1 and 2).}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        %%\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption of subfigure 2\\(e.g., load cases 3 and 4).}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Comparison of two subfigures.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also need the first line of caption aligned with the second line of the caption, as the `format=hang` did.